# Excel VBA Limiting a search (or using Find) within a single row, or a range of rows

Tags: vba, excel

I know that I can limit a find to within specified columns using Range, but can I do the same with rows?

I'm looking for specific data that can be found in a certain row and don't wish to slow my search process by allowing the scan of the entire sheet.
How to go about it?

Comment: Instead of `Rng.Find...` use  `Rows(5).Find`.  Replace 5 with a variable or a range as necessary. Alternative, `Set Rng = Rows(5)` `Rng.Find...`  `Rows()` and `Columns()` are sub-types of `Range`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Find()` method should be qualified with a valid `Range` object. Rows and Columns are just a collection of cells and are therefore valid range objects too:

```
Sub Foo()

Dim foundMe As Excel.Range
Set foundMe = Rows(1).Find("Bar") '// Searches row 1 for "Bar"

MsgBox foundMe.Value

End Sub
```